# Flow type for useMemo hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Simple question.

I've declared a string array using `useMemo` and I'm struggling to get the correct flow type for it.

I have the following :

```
const fruits: () => Array<string> = useMemo(() => ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas'],[]);
```

and get the following flow error

**`Cannot assign useMemo(...) to fruits because array literal [1] is incompatible with function type [2].`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the following works. It's just as simple as using :

```
const fruits: Array<string> = useMemo(() => ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas']);
```